# How to validate nested objects for Null values

Tags: java, validation, design-patterns

I am working on a service which receives a request from the upstream system.

- The request can have about 300 fields.
- My task is to process the order, but before processing the order, I have to perform data validation.
- Data validation mainly involves null & empty checks. I have to check at-least whether all the mandatory fields are neither empty nor null.

Order DTO:

```
public class Order{
   private String orderId;
   private String sourceOrder;
   private String destinationSystem;
   private String orderingTimeStamp;
   private List<Mapper> properties;
          ....
}
```

I don't want to check null on each step, like
`if(sourceOrder!=null && !sourceOrder.isEmpty())`, as I would end up writing a lot of boilerplate code.
So, I thought before processing the order, let's validate the order for `null & empty` checks. If all mandatory values are present, then process the order else reject the order.

I am aware of `@NotNull` annotation, but that won't work for nested objects for example `private List<Mapper> properties`, will have a list of objects. Out of those elements I want to validate only selected and not all.

For example, I have to validate only `"firstName", "lastName", "Address"` in the `List<Mapper> properties`, not all.

Is there any way to achieve it, or do we have any design pattern/framework to do this?
Please help.

Comment: What format is the request in? JSON?

Comment: yes, the format is JSON.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is define a `validate` function on all nested properties.

First, you want to define a seperate class which has the different flags to control validation behaviour.

```
public class OrderValidationOptions {
  // Your options
}
```

Then or our nested type:

```java
public class Mapper {
 // Other Code

 public boolean validate(OrderValidationOptions options) {
   // validation logic
 }
}
```

And similarly in the `Order` class:

```java
public class Order {
 // Other Code
 private List<Mapper> properties;

 public boolean validate(OrderValidationOptions options) {
   // Other logic
   if (this.properties != null) {
     for(Mapper property: this.properties) {
       property.validate(options)
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. This solution will have validation on all fields. As per my requirement, I have to do validation based on the processing. For example for I request I maybe validating 10 & for another I may be validating only 5 fields.

Comment: you can always parameterize it. create a class `ValidationOptions`, and pass them through the calls

Answer (score 0):

All Lists and Sets extend the Interface `Collection`. I make use of that. When you have any Object `example` of any type, you can call `validate(example);` and the right result will return.
If example implements Collection, the first method will be called, otherwise the second.

```
public boolean validate(Collection c) {
   if(c == null) return false;
   if(c.isEmpty()) return false;
   return true;
}

public boolean validate(Object obj) {
   return obj != null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer.  Your answer would work for root-collection validation. My question is mainly to validate nested objects.